# C# WebClient.OpenRead how to know if eof?

Tags: c#

How do i know when im at the end of the file?

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: QuickTime/7.6.2");
Stream stream = Client.OpenRead(link);
```

Client.IsBusy does return false..
and i cant figure out how to access Client.ResponseHeaders
stream.Length gives me a exception? so how sould i know if im at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading from the stream returns 0 bytes, you're at the end. If the read call blocks, you're not yet at the end. This is true for all stream access in .NET.

From MSDN [Stream.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(VS.80).aspx):

> > Read returns 0 only when there is no more data in the stream and no more is expected (such as a closed socket or end of file). An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached.